# Bind an empty object list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nullreferenceexception

I´m trying to populate a list in a view dynamically. I mean the user will choose some "items" (this items are also objects) and with the selection I have to populate a new list of objects. The problem is that when I try to bind a  @Html.TextBoxFor() with the empty list just to save those selected values later of course there are no objects in the list yet so it produces an null reference exception.

// some code to explain the problem - This DDL brings the all "items" in order the user can choose some of them //

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemsToSelect, new SelectList(Model.ItemsToSelect.Select(s => new { s.id, s.descripcion}).ToList(), "id", "descripcion"))
```

and this code is trying to relate the empty list with a combo just to have the object when I do the POSTBACK

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.selectedItems[0].id)
```

This last textbox is the one who is null at the beginning. One solution that actually works is populating this list with empty objects but I think there MUST be another way to solve it.

Thanks to all, I hope someone understand what I`m trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem, you're trying to bind a textbox to an item that doesn't exist at the time the page is rendered.

The solution is simple, just create a normal HTML `<input type='text' name='someProperty' />` control, and give it the `name` property that matches your model. ASP.NET MVC will automatically add this to your model when you post the form.

```
public class MyModel
{
    string someProperty {get; set;}
}
```

You may have to populate the value of the textbox when an item is selected, using a bit of jquery, eg something like. `$('#myDDL').change(function() { $('#myTextbox').val($('#myDDL').val()) });`

Alternatively you can probably just submit the dropdown list itself using the `name` method above, it'll send the selected value I think, and probably comma delimit them if more than one is selected.

Comment: Thanks @SLC, I already solved my problem with something like that, I´m using javascript to fill an editor with the correct values. My mistake was that I wanted to fill a new list insted of using the same one. I think I can´t create a new objetc in the view and I had to change my way of solve the problem. Now the same item list only postbacks the items that user selects.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check that `selectedItems` is not null?

```
@if (Model.selectedItems != null && Model.selectedItems.Count() > 0) {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.selectedItems[0].id)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Darren but The issue is that the "selectedItem" should populate with items dynamically, is correct to have an empty list at the begining when the user selects an item this item should be in the new list. (I think the problem is how to create a new object for the list in the view)

Comment: just add an else to this if statement producing an empty textbox if the selected items is NULL and I think this solves the problem as I understand it.  You optionally do an INLINE if statement otherwise

Comment: I think I can´t explain myself properly, the issue is that I need to add a new Item into the SelectedItem (actually item and selectedItems are not the same object type but I´m trying to simplify the domain) list. Validating if the list is empty or not isn´t the solution i´m looking for.